# Stop HTML converting an & code

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have an HTML table that displays information from a database, and one of the database fields contains a parameter list such as:

```
id=eff34-435-567rt-65u&notification=5
```

But when I display this in the table the &not becomes ¬

I know that you can manually force it to print the right way by using

```
&amp;not
```

But I would really rather be able to just use something to force the HTML to ignore the code so I can just pull the text straight from the database and print it to the table without having to do a regex to find out if there are any & and replace them with &amp; I tried using the <pre> tag but that did not work.

Is there any way to force the HTML to print exactly what is typed for that specific td field?

Comment: What programming language are you using, it depends on the programming language as it is the language that escapes your code and not html

Comment: PHP through a CodeIgniter framework gets the information from a mysql database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing practical (CDATA doesn't have [browser support](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.3) in `text/html` mode). Write proper HTML instead.

You should be running anything that comes out of the database through a conversion function to make it HTML safe anyway (to protect against XSS if nothing else). PHP has `htmlspecialchars()`, TT has `| html`. Whatever you are using should have something other then a regex.

Answer (score 2):

`&amp;` is the correct HTML encoding for the `&`. You will need to write the `&amp;not` for it to display correctly.

If you're pulling from a database, you can use whatever programming language that is available to you to decode HTML entities for you.

For example, in PHP, you could use [`htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 1):

most frameworks have HTML Encode functions.

in JavaScript: `encode`

in C# .NET: [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just run an HTMLEncode on the string before outputting it. Every server-side scripting language I know of has a built in command to do this. Not to mention that you are eventually going to run into another character that causes problems too.

ASP.NET: HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode
PHP: htmlentities

Regex should definitely NOT be necessary.